# JAXB : unmarshalexception - with linked exception: [java.io.IOException: Stream closed]

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, sax

I am trying to parse my xml using SAX ,I want to use JaxB to build my map my element name and its value.I also want to override startElement and endElemnt but I have reached here until so far and I am getting unmarshal exception.Any help is appreciated!.

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(my.class);

```
      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  


     UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = jaxbUnmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();

     SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
     SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
     XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
     xr.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);


     InputStream inputStream =   this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.xml");
     InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);

     xr.parse(inputSource);



      JAXBElement  element  = (JAXBElement) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputSource);


       //or if I unmarahall to specific class object still i get same exception.

    } catch (JAXBException e) {  
     // some exception occured  
       e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unmarshal the `InputSource` after you have used a SAX parse on it. To get the object call `getResult` on the `UnmarshallerHandler`.

Comment: So how can i unmarshal the xml file to a java class object?

Comment: @SriHari - Is this the information you are looking for:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: In the above link i'm getting response null. Please Once see the pojo class for xml response?