# JAXB UnmarshalException linked with java.io.IOException: stream is closed

Tags: java, jaxb, inputstream

We have an input stream which we pass it to the JAXB Unmarshaller

```
String file = "com.package.mapping.xml"
InputStream inputStream = Properties.getConnection().read(file).getInputStream();
Unmarshaller unMarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(SpacesMapping.class).createUnmarshaller();
        return (SpacesMapping) unMarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

This return you a Jaxb object but also it throws a JAXB UnmarshalException linked with java.io.IOException: stream is closed.

Could you help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAXB : unmarshalexception - with linked exception: \[java.io.IOException: Stream closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900440/jaxb-unmarshalexception-with-linked-exception-java-io-ioexception-stream)

Comment: No this doesn't work